# Loud beeping noise when USB port is used with dongle

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, audio, mouse

I currently have a Msi latop and i often use a wireless controller that uses a dongle. Whenever i place the dongle in a different usb port along with my mouse or in some cases randomly i lose the ability to use my touch pad or mouse and every attempt at moving the cursor resolves in a loud audio beeping noise.

Comment: please add OS and device info as they would help to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some electrical issue. Are you aware that not all usb ports provide the same current? maybe there's one on yours that provides enough to power the dongle, but the others don't and when you plug it in it attempts to drain too much power, messing with the other things. Try running it from and externally powered USB hub (i.e. one that comes with an adapter), if it works with that then this is probably the issue.